Indented Stack Snippets don’t render well
This Markdown:
- foo

  

  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    console.log("hello, world!");
  } else {
    console.log("goodbye, cruel world!");
  }

  




Renders as:


foo


> 
>       if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
>         console.log("hello, world!");
>       } else {
>         console.log("goodbye, cruel world!");
>       }
> 
>   





Oh wait, it works even worse embedded in a blockquote.  Well, let me try again:

foo


  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    console.log("hello, world!");
  } else {
    console.log("goodbye, cruel world!");
  }

  




And in preview it looks even more bizarre:



Wait, never mind – rendered on the page is worse after all:




Wow, what an utter trainwreck: https://i.sstatic.net/QwNHsjnZ.png
